Incorrect output voltage from TPS54202
I want to use a TPS54202 to convert from 12V to 3.3V. The circuit design below was proposed by TI Web Bench. I didn't have a 8.2uH inductor, so I used 6.8uH instead. When I built it, it produced 4.45V, not 3.3V. I checked the circuit thoroughly and could find no issues, so I built a second one: this also produced 4.49V.
The output voltage remains the same at zero load and with a 470R load.
The inductor is a 5mm square encapsulated inductor, rated for 2.1A. I changed it to a CD54 10uH inductor (1.5A), and the output voltage remained the same.
I found this question, where the OP got 7.1V rather than 5.18V. Note: the OP's circuit uses a 49R resistor, and both answers incorrectly assume that it's 49k. That's probably not the cause of the OP's problem. I used 1% resistors in my circuit, and have checked that they are in spec.
My circuit produces voltages that are 35% and 36% high, and this person's circuit produces a voltage that is 37% high.

The signal on the SW pin looks like this:

The Vout and FB signals are similar. The voltage on the FB pin is 807mV with ~4mV ripple. Note that the datasheet quotes Vfb as 596mV, so the actual Vfb is 35% higher.
The PCB is a single sided prototype, and looks like this:


What's the inductor you used? Does the problem get better, worse or no difference with increased load?

Good. Please update the question with that information. The problem lies elsewhere. What does your layout look like? What does an oscilloscope capture on SW and FB pins look like?

SMPS and single layer PCBs does generally not combine well. Are you feeding in Vin via that bottom side trace and up via the via to your 1 uF input capacitor?

@winny as I said, it's a single side board: the vias and bottom copper artwork are just to remind me where to make additional connections. The track from the electrolytic to the 1uF capacitor is a 20AWG wire on top of the board.

What is the used voltage at the EN input? The limit is 7 V and I remember accidentially connecting it to VIN with bad results.

@jens Yes, I noticed that limit. I'm using 3.3V.

I compared my last two layouts using this IC with your design. I never used C5 and my voltage divider has a lower impedance with 10 kohm as R5. On the input side I used 10uF/35V/X7R + 100nF, on the output 2 x 22uF/10V/X7R + 100nF. The second layout uses 100uF/16V aluminum electrolytic at the output. Both had no issues except my EN voltage bug.
